# In Chrome ajax async postback end does not work

Tags: asp.net, ajax, google-chrome, asynchronous, callback

I have a sample app developed in asp.NET 3.5. On my master page I use following code to display an GIF while loading the page. It works correctly on IE and FF, but fails in Chrome. On pressing the submit button, the server gets the request and completes its processing and while that is happening the browser shows the loading GIF as expected.However the postback never completes and user keeps on looking at the progress GIF. I wonder where I have goofed up... Pls help!

```
                             // Get the instance of PageRequestManager.
                             var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
                             // Add initializeRequest and endRequest
                             prm.add_initializeRequest(prm_InitializeRequest);
                             prm.add_endRequest(prm_EndRequest);
                             // Called when async postback begins
                             function prm_InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
                                 // get the divImage and set it to visible
                                 var panelProg = $get('divImage');  
                                 if( panelProg != null)             
                                 {
                                    panelProg.style.display = '';
                                     // Disable button that caused a postback
                                     $get(args._postBackElement.id).disabled = true;
                                 }
                             }
                             // Called when async postback ends
                             function prm_EndRequest(sender, args) {
                                 // get the divImage and hide it again
                                 var panelProg = $get('divImage'); 
                                 if(panelProg != null)
                                 {               
                                    panelProg.style.display = 'none';
                                    $get(sender._postBackSettings.sourceElement.id).disabled = false;

                                 }
                             }
```

My divImage is simple

```
  <div id="divImage" style="display: none">

        <img id="imgId1" src="../../App_Themes/Images/progressbar.gif" style="border-width:0px;" />
        <br />
        Please wait...

    </div>
```

Comment: Press Ctrl+Shift+J in Chrome. There should be some new area at the bottom of the window. Click on "Console". Are there any error messages?

Comment: Gee! yes. there are errors. I think its config issue of scripts...
<br/>
Uncaught Sys.ScriptLoadFailedException: Sys.ScriptLoadFailedException: The script 'http://XXX.XXX.XX.XXX/APPNAME/ChartAxd.axd?rs=/wEFHlNvdXJjZUNvZGUuQWpheC5EdW5kYXNDaGFydC5qcw==&ver=7.0.0.1803' failed to load. Check for:

 Inaccessible path.

 Script errors. (IE) Enable 'Display a notification about every script error' under advanced settings.

 Missing call to Sys.Application.notifyScriptLoaded().

Answer (score 5):

Add the following script to your page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.Browser.WebKit = {}; //Safari 3 is considered WebKit
    if( navigator.userAgent.indexOf( 'WebKit/' ) > -1 )
    {
        Sys.Browser.agent = Sys.Browser.WebKit;
        Sys.Browser.version = parseFloat( navigator.userAgent.match(/WebKit\/(\d+(\.\d+)?)/)[1]);
        Sys.Browser.name = 'WebKit';
    }
</script>
```

See more at: http://blog.joeydaly.com/uncaught-sys-scriptloadfailedexception-sys-scriptloadfailedexception

Answer (score 0):

I have problems with ajax in Chrome in my dev environment(localhost without a .something domain). When I switch to acceptance Chrome works fine. In what environment are you working?

What you could try is change the dev url in your host file to something with an extention.

Comment: Well the problem exist in dev as well as prod env (a site with registered domain). It exists even if we access it using the IP.